# CoreData backgroundContext save doesn't save and is lost

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm having a problem saving things in the background. So I have 2 operations that I chain with RxSwift.
The first items are saved and when I fetch them on a main context all the information is there.
But in the second operation I fetch the same object and I update it with more information.
Now whatever I do there it never updates the entity.

This is my coredata code:

```
class CoreDataStack {
    static let modelName = "Mo_Application"
    static let model: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = Bundle(for: CoreDataStack.self).url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.storeContainer.viewContext
    }()

    lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: CoreDataStack.modelName, managedObjectModel: CoreDataStack.model)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

    func newDerivedContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.storeContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    }

    func saveContext() throws {
        try? self.saveContext(mainContext)
    }

    func saveAndWaitContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
        if context != mainContext {
            try self.saveAndWaitDerivedContext(context)
            return
        }

        context.performAndWait {
            try? context.save()
        }
    }

    func saveAndWaitDerivedContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
        context.performAndWait {
            try? context.save()
            try? self.saveAndWaitContext(self.mainContext)
        }
    }
}
```

What I do in the first operation:

```
let context = coreDataStack.newDerivedContext()

let object = Foo(context: context)
object.name = "Name 1"

try coreDataStack.saveAndWaitDerivedContext(context)
maybe(.success(self)) (RxSwift to complete)
```

In the second operation I first fetch the object:

```
let context = coreDataStack.newDerivedContext()
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Foo> = Foo.fetchCreatedBy(user: user)
let objects: [Foo] = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
let object = objects.first { $0.id == self.id }
if let object = object {
    object.name = "Name updated"
}
try coreDataStack.saveAndWaitDerivedContext(context)
maybe(.success(self))
```

When I now do a fetch on my mainContext the old value is still there.

When I call my saveAndWaitDerivedContext the background context hasChanges. But when I then save the mainContext it doesn't have changes? Is that normal?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on `NSPersistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()`:

> This new context will be associated with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` directly and is set to consume `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` broadcasts automatically.

This gives a hint that your background context writes directly into the persistent store. Main context will not know about this if you don't merge the changes made in the background context into it.

You should listen to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification from the background context, and merge changes from it into the main context.

```
func saveAndWaitDerivedContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
    let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: context, queue: .main) { (notification) in
        self.mainContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification)
    }
    context.performAndWait {
        try? context.save()    
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Comment: Will try that. What I found out was that when I do the changes in the block of performAndWait everything works. Are we not allowed to do changes on objects outside the perform block?

Comment: > Are we not allowed to do changes on objects outside the perform block? < Yes, if you modify managed objects that belong to the `NSManagedObjectContext` with `.privateQueue` concurrency type (which is true for your background context), you should modify MOs only inside the `performBlock` / `performBlockAndWait` block.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer said, because `newBackgroundContext()` function of `NSPersistentContainer` returns a new context that will be associated with the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` directly, you can tell your main context to automaticaly merge changes saved to its persistent store by setting `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` property to `true`:

```
lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    self.storeContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    return self.storeContainer.viewContext
}()
```

As the [automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1845237-automaticallymergeschangesfrompa) documentation states:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the context automatically
> merges changes saved to its **persistent store coordinator or parent
> context**.

If the above code doesn't work, maybe you should set this property after `NSPersistentContainer` loads its persistent stores:

```
lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: CoreDataStack.modelName, managedObjectModel: CoreDataStack.model)
    container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
    return container
}()
```

Comment: That merges changes from `parentContext`, not from the persistent store.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk I updated my answer with the documentation of the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` property.

Comment: @user1007522 I tried that on a project with the exact same setup as yours and it works. Does it give you any error?